# Indent AnnotatedString without space at the top or bottom of text

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm displaying list items with AnnotatedString texts.
Each item has a hyphen and a Paragraph style for indenting the text.

```
    val text = buildAnnotatedString {
        append("-")
        pushStyle(
            ParagraphStyle(
                textIndent = TextIndent(
                    firstLine = 20.sp,
                    restLine = 20.sp
                ),
            )
        )
        append("This is a long text i want indented with the space at the top or bottom.")
        pop()
    }
```

However, there's a space/padding at the top and bottom of text, not making it aligned with the hyphen.
See image below.

[image]

How do a achieve indentation without space at the top and bottom of text

Comment: Have you already found a solution?